# Mass insert with Redis fails with strange errors

Tags: python, redis

I am playing with Redis mass import using the pipe and have the following Python script:

```
mydata = ""
mydata += "*4\r\n$4\r\nHSET\r\n$%d\r\n%s\r\n$%d\r\n%s\r\n$%d\r\n%s\r\n" % (len('myhash'), 'myhash', len('myfield'), 'myfield', len('myvalue'), 'myvalue')

print mydata.rstrip()
```

It produces:

```
$ python redis_test.py
*4
$4
HSET
$6
myhash
$7
myfield
$7
myvalue
```

Output of piping:

```
$ python redis_test.py | redis-cli -h rnode -n 5 --pipe --pipe-timeout 1
All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...
ERR unknown command '2'
ERR unknown command '$4'
ERR wrong number of arguments for 'echo' command
ERR unknown command '$20'
ERR unknown command '�˛�ƩA\m���pm��X�[�'
No replies for 1 seconds: exiting.
errors: 6, replies: 6
```

Although I am getting it to populate the DB, I would like to know what's causing those errors?

```
rnode:6379[5]> keys *
1) "myhash"
rnode:6379[5]> hgetall myhash
1) "myfield"
2) "myvalue"
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my own question: I didn't know it needed a final CRLF, hence this:

```
print mydata.rstrip()
```

Became:

```
print mydata
```

Result:

```
$ python redis_test.py | redis-cli -h rnode -n 5 --pipe --pipe-timeout 10
All data transferred. Waiting for the last reply...
Last reply received from server.
errors: 0, replies: 1
```